# How can force change the day in datetime in php

Tags: php, date, loops, datetime

```
$date = date_create('2013-10-27');// This is the date that inputed in textbox and that format is (Y-m-d)

$date = date_create('2013-10-10');// and if i click the button i want to force change the 27 to 10?
```

Should i use date_modify and do some loop or there's other way to change it in easy way rather than looping.

Comment: Your accepted answer is not the best one. I would recommend [Glavic's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19153668/212940).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Note: If you're just trying to modify the value of a day on the date that comes from a submitted `<input>` from a `<form>`. You could try these steps:

```
$date = '2013-10-27'; // pass the value of input first.

$date = explode('-', $date); // explode to get array of YY-MM-DD

//formatted results of array would be
$date[0] = '2013'; // YY
$date[1] = '10';   // MM
$date[2] = '17';   // DD

// when trigger a button to change the day value.

$date[2] = '10'; // this would change the previous value of DD/Day to this one. Or input any value you want to execute when the button is triggered

// then implode the array again for datetime format.

$date = implode('-', $date); // that will output '2013-10-10'.

// lastly create date format

$date = date_create($date);
```

Comment: This is ridiculous. The OP was already using DateTime which is quite capable of providing a good solution. See [Galvic's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19153668/212940).

Answer (score 49):

```
$in = date_create('2013-10-27');

// example 1
$out = date_create($in->format('Y-m-10'));
echo $out->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

// example 2
$out = clone $in;
$out->setDate($out->format('Y'), $out->format('m'), 10);
echo $out->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

// example 3
$out = clone $in;
$out->modify((10 - $out->format('d')) . ' day');
echo $out->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/52195).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Wonder why OP chose the other one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **native PHP** "[date_date_set](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php#refsect1-datetime.setdate-examples)" function to make this change.

```
$date = date_create('2013-10-27');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
2013-10-27
date_date_set($date,
              date_format($date, 'Y'),
              date_format($date, 'm'),
              10);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
2013-10-10
```

Or using the **Object-Oriented** style:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-10-27');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
2013-10-27
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'), 10);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
2013-10-10
```

Answer (score -2):

`$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-10-10"));`

Updated:
to force to change the day from 27 to 10

1) get the year and month

`$date = date("Y-m-", strtotime( $_POST['user_selected_date'] ));`

2) append your day

`$date .= '10';`

Also you can finish it in ONE step
`$date = date("Y-m-10", strtotime( $_POST['user_selected_date'] ));`

Comment: what if its different month? or year?

Comment: Please expand your answer to make it more useful.

Answer (score -4):

Use PCRE Function

`$date = '2013-10-27';`
`$new_date = preg_replace("/\d{2}$/", "10", $date);`

[preg_replace manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: If you're using REGEX, you're most likely doing it wrong. This is exactly that.